# Tensorflow Max-Min pool layer

Tags: tensorflow

is it possible in Tensorflow to implement max - min pooling layer?

I would like to extract the boundaries from the images and I believe this would be useful.

Comment: I have never head the term "max-min pooling", nor does Google give any results. You will need to explain what exactly you need as well as show what you have tried so far/where you are stuck. This is not a code-writing service. To answer "is it possible": Yes, probably, but I doubt that helps you very much.

Comment: @xdurch0 ,  MaxPooling2D gets max value of some k x k matrix. I'm thinking about a pooling that would take max and min values from this k x k matrix and return a subtraction. If it's not implemented in TF then I wonder if someone could guide me on the right track

Comment: Well here's a rough sketch of how it could be done -- the exact implementation would depend on the framework/API you are using. 1. Do a normal max pooling. Let's call the result `M`. 2. Do min pooling like this: `m = -max_pool(-x)`. There is no min pooling in TF, but we can do max pool of the negative and then apply the negative again to revert to the original. 3. `M - m` would be the difference of the two.

Comment: @xdurch0 that would be tensorflow. I like the workaround with min, however this calculation would need to be done inside of the kernel. I wonder if it's possible to subclass MaxPooling2D with some input data parameter. I saw some examples of subclassing other layers but not this one.